# C finite sequences from page 74 of book 'The Concrete Tetrahedron by Manuel Kauers ,Peter Paule'

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, proof-explanation, power-series, generating-functions

[image]

In the attached picture how is eq 2 obtained from eq 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a formal proof but a reasonable explanation which should suffice.
Note we don't necessarily have to consider 'derived from eq 1'.
Label the first expression, that is the one with no x's and has $(n\geq0)$ written to it's right, as  Eq $0$ even though is not labeled as such in the picture.
Multiply eq 2 by $x^r$ and show coeff's of $x^n$ all $n>-1$ are $0$. Consider each of the r+1 lines as depicted in the picture for Eq 2 and in all except the last r+1'th
line will, aside from a same overall cst multiplier, consider the two parts : generating function a(x) and the $-(a_0+...)$ part.
For $n=0$ only need consider 1st line and coeff of $ x^0$ in a(x) which is $a_0$ and in $-(a_0+...)$ is $-a_0$ so obviously coeff of $x^0$ is $0$. For $n=1$ must consider lines 1 and 2 and in line 1 get $a_1$ out of the a(x) and $-a_1$ out of the $-(a_0+a_1...)$ 2nd line so in both lines the coeff of x cancels in both lines individually.
And we can see by sort of induction it goes the same type of way that is coeff's of $x^n$ cancel in each line individually for $n<r$ and it is clear the coeff's
of $x^n$ for $n<r$ are $0$ on lhs of eq 2 because of cancellations in parts of the $a(x)$ part and $-(a_0+...)$ part in each line except the last. For $x^n, n<r$ the last line is never considered since the lowest power of x is r because always considering eq 2 multiplied by $x^r$. For coeff of $x^n$ for all $n>r-1$ all r+1 lines must be combined and we use eq $0$. Only terms in the a(x) contribute and no terms in the $-(a_0+...)$ parts contribute. In the 1st line use the $a_n x^n$ term out of a(x), in the 2nd line use $a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$ out of a(x) times $c_{r-1}x$ and so on thru line r where use $a_{n-r+1}x^{n-r+1}$ out of a(x) times $c_1x^{r-1}$ and in the last r+1 line use the $a_{n-r}x^{n-r}$ out of a(x) times $c_0 x^r$ and at the end sum all r+1 lines contributions which sum to $0$    for the coeff. of $x^n, n>r-1$ because of eq. $0$ which is valid for any $n>-1$.